# Menubar constraints in BigSur

Tags: swift, cocoa, macos-big-sur

I have the following code that works fine in Mojave but it looks bad in BigSur(see the pic below) How can I push the icon to the left.

Sorry, I'm not good with writing constraints programmatically so the existing constrains might be wrong(but they worked on the prev versions of macos)

```swift
        let itemImage = NSImage(named: "menubar3")
        itemImage?.isTemplate = true
        statusItem?.button?.image = itemImage
        statusItem?.button?.imagePosition = NSControl.ImagePosition.imageLeft
        

        stack = NSStackView(views: views)
        stack?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        statusItem?.button?.addSubview(stack!)

        statusItem?.button?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stack!, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: statusItem?.button, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 30))
        
        statusItem?.button?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stack!, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: statusItem?.button, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -5))
```

[image]

**UPD**

Not sure if it helps

```swift
    var statusItem: NSStatusItem?

    ....

    @objc func configureStatusItem() {
        // Status Bar
        var views: [StatusItemSectionView] = []
        
        for item in statsViewModels {
            
            if item.isValid {
                let section = StatusItemSectionView(
                    frame: NSRect(),
                    viewModel: item
                )
                
                views.append(section)
                
            }
            
        }

        
        let statusBar = NSStatusBar.system
        statusItem = statusBar.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        statusItem?.button?.action = #selector(self.statusBarButtonClicked(sender:))
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that creates `statusItem`.

Comment: Also, please add if this works with Catalina. (Editorial, not an edit. I absolutely *hate* these names. In this case? You speak about Mohave - which I believe is 10.14 - completely skipping over 10.15 for 11.0. Yeah, please, does this work in what I guess is the final version of OS X? Namely Catalina?)

Comment: @dfd My thought was if it works on Big Sur then it should work on Catalina. I personally don't plan to upgrade from Mojave and just installed Big Sur on a separate volume :) With build target 10.12, it worked fine on Mojave. It seems that the icon is always centred, ignoring the `ImagePosition.imageLeft` rule.

Comment: BUT - sorry for screaming :-) - it helps to debug the issue. If it *doesn't* work on Catalina then the issue *isn't* restricted to BigSur. My work (CoreImage) pretty much means most things are done on physical devices. But I'd think this issue can be done in a simulator. (And if not, is that part of the issue?) BigSur (to me) was mainly a UI upgrade. Catalina? Much more. (Think 32 bit apps. And yes, that noise for you. Still.)